# Google Play Books enhanced with video not working

Tags: html5-video, epub, adobe-indesign, google-books, epub3

I am developing an enhanced ebook for Google Play Books in fixed layout epub. I am using Adobe **Indesign** to develop this ebook. I am having great difficulty adding videos in my ebook. I have exhausted all possible options to embed the video. I have tried `HTML5 video` tag as suggested by the [official Google support](https://support.google.com/books/partner/answer/3316879?hl=en-GB). I have tried to embed youtube video using an `iframe` but no luck.

When I upload my ebook to **GPB** it doesn't display any video in case of HTML5 and in case of iframes `iframe` takes some real estate but shows up blank. The iframe however does show on web version of the app and videos stream alright.

How can I embed videos successfully in my ebook? either `HTML5` or `iframe` will do for me.

Comment: The "The iframe however does show on web version of the app and videos stream alright."  seems to suggest that your problem is with the Google Play Books app, not with the Google Play Books service in general, right? If so, which version of the GPB pp and on which device are you testing? Did you update the GPB app? Can you replicate the problem on other devices? --- In general, GPB "tweaks" the uploaded files before sending them to the app, in your case something might have gone wrong. Another possibility: the GPB is not capable of displaying your video. Contact GPB support.

Comment: Interactivity is not working like buttons and events added via Indesign "Button and Forms" option.
Using Nexus 7 tab.
Videos are done.